# Can I remove a PPA without affecting the software it provides?

Tags: uninstall, ppa

I installed a PPA for the very first time, according to instructions here. I achieved my goal (needed to install an application by the name Solaar), and now I wonder if I can uninstall the PPA without affecting the installed software (Solaar).

I manually added the PPA through *Software Center* > *edit* > *Software Sources*. And now there are three entries saved/logged.

What I am basically asking is; after the desired install is done, is the PPA disposable?

Comment: if you want to remove these PPA your installed software will not able to update after removing the PPA but your software work. no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can remove the PPA after you are done installing.

However, you will no longer receive updates to software.

PPAs are "software repositories". You get software from them. The software doesn't need it.

Think of your program as a bottle of milk. The PPA is the store. When you buy the milk, the milk (nor you) no longer needs the store. You can (if you want) never go to that store again. However, if the store recalls the milk, you can go back and get new milk.

Comment: Thank you for that metaphor, I think it cleared it up a bit for me. 

While I'm at it, I might as well ask... How many PPAs are there? Why are there so many different ones? Is there really a need for so many? 
Can't everyone contribute and sell from the same store?

Comment: @FuriousUser It's decentralized. Anyone can make and release their own software. It all designed for the user's choice. Like in Cydia, most apps come from a default repo. Those repos contain the most useful/common software. You can add more repos if you need more software. It depends on what you as the user needs.